# how to resolve an "out of frequency range" error after booting

Tags: nvidia, monitor

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10 from a Live CD and from a USB pendrive, but when I choose try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu from the boot screen, all I get is this message: "out of frequency range" and the monitor turns off in few seconds. I use an nVidea GeForce FX 5200 graphic card.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100712/server-doesnt-install#comment116579_100712

Comment: Check your keyboard as well, it looks like your caps lock is blocked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried booting it in "Safe mode"? I can't remember if the LiveCD has that option or not. If that doesn't work you may want to try to download and install from the "Alternative Install" Ubuntu disc.

Comment: I can't find the safe mode too. Can you give me more information about alternative install disk? thanks anyway.

Comment: On this page http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download there is a link for the bittorrent from Ubuntu to download the alternate install disk as well as other bittorrent downloads for other Ubuntu versions.